# How to Add DOCTYPE?

Tags: 7

In Css `Child selector` is not working in `IE 7` and `IE 8`. I google this problem and found that after adding a `DOCTYPE` it will solve. I add a `DOCTYPE` in `maintance.tpl.php` but it is not showing in souce. How to add it?

Comment: What theme are you using?

Comment: I am using bartik theme..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the version of Drupal you are using. On Drupal 6, you include all of the html document information in your page.tpl.php file. In Drupal 7 all of the document information is inherited from html.tpl.php in the core Drupal framework unless you create your own html.tpl.php.

Comment: Yes you are right, but why child selector not working in IE 7?